# "The common language runtime was unable to set the breakpoint"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crm

I am trying to develop a solution in CRM 2011 from VS 2010. When it works it's sort of OK (well CRM is a dog but the code works). But every so often it throws its toys out of the pram and refuses to debug. The current problem I have is that it protests that "The common language runtime was unable to set the breakpoint" on some lines in my routines. For example

```
private static TimeSpan FindWorkTime(DateTime T1, DateTime T2, Boolean[, ,] supporthours)
{
    TimeSpan SlotDuration = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
    TimeSpan fwt = new TimeSpan(0); // This I can put a break point on
    if (T2 > T1)                    // This tells me the CLR can not set a breakpoint!
    {
        DateTime T1S = servicecase.FindTimeSlotStart(T1);
        DateTime T2S = servicecase.FindTimeSlotStart(T2);
```

The code is not optimised. Breakpoints where studio (or CLR or whatever it is that's getting upset) decides to actually recognise them work. So why on earth do some lines and not others just refuse to debug!

I've had a search here and most of the answers involve optimisation (not on) or running two copies of studio (not the case).

Comment: Hi Jarvis, if [the answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17702626/241211) was posted by you, you can ask for that user account to be [merged into your own](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 0):

Solved at last. The answer of course is that CRM is a pile of ...

The code being run is not the code that has been deployed to the crm server. Even though there is only a single version of the DLL on the server and it is the same version that is on the development system it is not the version of the code that is being run at the server. The code run by CRM appears to be either the code from a DLL or a copy from the database which does not necessarily match the one in the DLL. For whatever reason even though the code was redeployed it appears that CRM still wants to take a old copy from the database. To be stable in addition to deploying the code it needs to be reregistered through their plugin registration tool.

(and that took far too long to find because I assumed that CRM would lie to me about what was failing to be honest the best solution would be to rewrite the app with something other than CRM)